# I want get sales for year using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get following result for given year

```
month | sales
jan     0.00
feb     4.00
mar     0.00
apr     45.00
.
.
.
.
dec    0.00
```

table that i have is "sales" and it has salse_value, sales_date as columns.

question is how can get above result using case when statement in MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to generate all month name and join it with your tables name so months that doesn't have records will have zero value for total sales

```
SELECT  a.MonthName, COALESCE(SUM(b.sales_value), 0) totalSales
FROM    
        (
            SELECT 'Jan' AS monthName, 1 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Feb' AS monthName, 2 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Mar' AS monthName, 3 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Apr' AS monthName, 4 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'May' AS monthName, 5 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Jun' AS monthName, 6 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Jul' AS monthName, 7 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Aug' AS monthName, 8 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Sep' AS monthName, 9 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Oct' AS monthName, 10 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Nov' AS monthName, 11 monthOrder
            UNION
            SELECT 'Dec' AS monthName, 12 monthOrder
        )   a LEFT JOIN sales b
                ON a.monthName = b.monthName
GROUP BY a.monthName
ORDER BY a.MonthOrder ASC
```

Comment: this i wat i got :) thank you John Woo  
  month salse
    Jan 0
    Feb 0
    Mar 0
    Apr 0
    May 0
    Jun 0
    Jul 0
    Aug 423
    Sep 0
    Oct 0
    Nov 295
    Dec 311

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(date_column), SUM(sales) sales
FROM TableName
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date_column);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get abbreviated names for month, you can try

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sales_date, '%b') AS month, SUM(sales_value)
FROM sales
GROUP BY month;
```

If there is no record of a particular month result won't contain any row for that month.

Comment: yes thank you . it work fine bro, but i want 0 for the sales_value that month doesn't have values. I think you got it what i say